# Copying data into a buffer (byte array)

Tags: python, python-bytearray

I am trying to copy a blob of data (some bytes) into a larger block at some position. I can do this easily enough in C, but now I am doing it in Python and I am curious as to what is the best/correct way to do this.

The way I did it was:

```
struct.pack_into("p", buffer, pos, str(data))
```

Where data and buffer are of type bytearray. Python would not let me copy the data into the buffer without converting it to a string (see the type conversion above), so I was wondering what is the correct way to insert one bytearray into another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytearray` objects are [mutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable), you can copy the contents of one into another at a given position by assigning to a slice:

```
buffer[pos:pos + len(data)] = data
```

There is no need or use for `struct.pack_into()` here. Note that `data` can be any iterable of integers, provided they fall in the range 0-255; it doesn't have to be a `bytes` or `bytearray` object.

Demo:

```
>>> buffer = bytearray(10)
>>> data = bytes.fromhex('deadbeef')
>>> pos = 3
>>> buffer[pos:pos + len(data)] = data
>>> buffer
bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\xde\xad\xbe\xef\x00\x00\x00')
```

Comment: Thanks! Good answer - The slice of bytearray buffer from pos to pos + len(data) is replaced by the contents of the iterable bytearray data.